# Git suddenly much slower on win 8

Tags: windows-8, git

Have to use windows at work (Oh joy) and while git for windows was always really slow compared to git on linux, since yesterday it's a bit ridiculous.

`git status` runs just fine, but `git diff` and `git log` take at least 15 seconds to appear, and opening a new terminal takes longer.

Running git as administrator solves these issues, but that's the entire reason the `core.fscache` option exists and yes - it's turned on.

I've tried rebooting, installing a new version of git... Does anyone have any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: You have verfied you are running the current version of Git on Windows?  There are two other options that might help, [Msysgit bash is horrendously slow in Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835775/msysgit-bash-is-horrendously-slow-in-windows-7), have you tried to enable those?  When you set the option, you set it as a normal user, not the Administrator user right?  Worth pointing out that, `core.fscach`, is enabled by default in Git 2.8+

Comment: Yes I installed the latest version today in the vain hope it would fix it. And I've had those options enabled for over a year (But it suddenly got slow as hell yesterday)

Comment: It was an external firewall. What does an external firewall have to do with a local file operation like `git diff` you ask? No-one will ever know. Such is windows.